# AngularJS select doesn't work without ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, ng-options

Does anyone know why in AngularJS, the `select` selector doesn't work without the `ng-model`?

```
<select ng-model="bla_bla" ng-options="obj.value as obj.key for obj in languages"/>
<select ng-options="obj.value as obj.key for obj in languages"/>
```

The first line of code above will work while the second one will not work.
Why ???

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the `select` tag within an Angular app generates the `ng-select` directive, which is an HTML `SELECT` element plus angular data-binding.  Looking in the Angular source for this `select` directive, here are the first few lines from its `link` method:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
    // if ngModel is not defined, we don't need to do anything
    if (!ctrls[1]) return;
    ...
```

So it is actually built into the framework to abort linking the `directive` if `ngModel` is not defined, and so no binding takes place.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu - You could just provide `ng-model` with a dummy variable.

Comment: that will save the data

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu Obviously.  But you don't have to use the data, which is why it's a 'dummy' variable.  You should ask a new question if this is unclear to you.