# ng-options is not compiled by $compile in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have tried a diretive without using template option in diretive, where i have a field which is a html string which i'm trying to compile using $compile in directive but it doesn't work.Not sure where i'm going wrong.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egyxjo42/1/

Directive name: `my-dropdown-b`

Comment: Do include your jsfiddle code in the question itself as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you work without template the ng-model from defined element is not transcluded to a new element, so you have to add the ng-model your self

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var ele = "<select ng-options='i.id as i.name for i in foodB' ng-model='"+attrs.ngModel+"'></select>";

        element.html(ele);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
```

Comment: could you explain in detail why `ng-model` is required..explanation would appreciated

Comment: hi @pankajparkar, here is an answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/16645107/2938008